# RStudio and biber

Tags: biber, rstudio

Can someone please help me get the code below to work but by running biber, not bibtex? I have a biblatex style (nejm) that only works with biber.  I'm currently running RStudio 0.98.501 and this is the first line of the log file.

> ```
> This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
> (format=xelatex     2013.5.30)  25 MAR 2014 17:55 entering extended
> mode
> ```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{test,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%\addbibresource{/Users/simon/Documents/simon.bib}
\begin{document}
Test text 

\parencite{test} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: You must at least change the value of option `backend` …

Comment: When I change to `backend=biber` I have no problem compiling your code. (I have the same `XeTeX` installed.) What problems do you have?

Comment: Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...


Package biblatex Warning: File 'test.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.
3.

Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test.bbl' found.
(./test.bbl
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name 
                                                  
l.32 \endentry

Comment: Sorry, the above is the one error message I can find in the log file.  I seem to recall having to upgrade biber because I encountered the same problem working in the TexShop environment, but I can't recall how I fixed the problem.
 @Martin

Comment: @spindoctor what versions of biblatex and biber do you use? Do you get warnings when you run biber?

Comment: Hi there: I have biblatex 2.8 and biber 1.8. The thing is, I can run biber from TexShop and a .blg file is produced with this as the first line:
[0] Config.pm:318> INFO - This is Biber 1.8
[0] Config.pm:321> INFO - Logfile is 'texshop.test.blg'
[171] biber-darwin:275> INFO - === Mon Mar 31, 2014, 10:19:14

But, when I run RStudio, no .blg is compiled. So maybe it's not even running Biber when I'm in Rstudio.